# How to make text flow from one table cell to the next

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

In a reporting solution based on Apache FOP, we want a layout where text (to be specific, a table) flows from one cell to the next when it becomes too much for the first cell. Is it possible to define text flow across table cells in xsl-fo? The three cells in question are part of a larger table which defines the layout of the page.

EDIT (clarifying the question):

We don't just want a bigger cell which takes all the text, but we want the text to flow from one cell to the next, like text on a multicolumn page, i.e. the text should flow from top to bottom of the first cell and continue at the top of the next cell in the row if necessary.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there is! It works like HTML's colspan:
http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#number-columns-spanned

Comment: Sorry, that is not what I meant. I will clarify my question.

Comment: Then you could use the same attribute (potentially as xsl:attribute tag), but combine it with a condition (xsl:choose / xsl:when / xsl:otherwise) after you check the length of the content in cell one. I'm afraid (and that may be your problem?) you would have to settle for using the string length as a measure here (http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-string-length). 




If you have complex cell content, I fear you cannot "pre-fetch" a sneak peek of how the document would look after generation, as the whole way FOP works is a pipeline - one direction only. As far as I know, of course.

Comment: As another thing you could try (I'm not sure this will work), you could set the attribute "overflow" on table-cell? 
http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#overflow

Comment: No, sorry, that's also not a solution. Overflow doesn't format the text. In fact, the text in question is a table. As far as I know, my colleagues found a solution using flows, but they had to twist the pagemaster layout quite heavily, and we would be quite happy to have a nicer solution.

Comment: Okay. I added the fop tag to your question, hope you find more people who could answer this.